# Isometry can be written as a composition

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help proving:

> Every isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be uniquely written as the
>   composition $t\circ k$ where $t$ is a translation and $k$ is an
>   isometry fixing the origin.

What do they exactly mean by "$k$ is an isometry *fixing the origin*" (I would like to know conceptually what they meant by that)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means $k(0) = 0$

Comment: @Cocopuffs That doesn't help paint a picture in my head. (I like your username btw)

Comment: A point $A$ is a *fixed point* of the transformation $T$ if $T(A)=A$. The origin is a fixed point of any rotation about the origin: the origin does not move.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is much better! Thanks!

Comment: An example always helps.

Comment: It is a repair service for broken origins. (Joking aside, when studying something new, I often find myself thrown by jargon such as this.)

Comment: @copper.hat I had to look up what jargon meant and it is a very good word that describes my difficulty in this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We give a very formal proof of the fact that there is such a translation $t$ and isometry $A$. The argument is basically group-theoretic.

Let $\phi$ be an isometry, and let $O$ be the origin. Suppose that $\phi(O)=A$. Let $t$ be the translation that takes the origin to $A$, and let $t^{-1}$ be the inverse of $t$. So $t^{-1}$ is the translation that takes $A$ to $O$.  Define $k$ by $k=t^{-1}\circ \phi$.

It probably clear that $\phi=t\circ k$. For $t\circ k=t\circ(t^{-1}\circ \phi)=(t\circ t^{-1})\circ\phi=\phi$.

Note that $k$ is an isometry, because it is a composition of two isometries. We check that if fixes the origin. To see this, apply $t^{-1}\circ\phi$ to $O$. We get $t^{-1}(\phi(O)$. But $\phi(O)=A$, and $t^{-1}(A)=O$.

The problem also asked us to show that $t$ and $k$ are **unique**. So suppose that $\phi=t\circ k=t'\circ k'$, where $t$ and $t'$ are translations and $k$ and $k'$ fix the origin. We need to show that $t=t'$ and $k=k'$.

Apply the transformation $t\circ k$ to the origin. We get $(t\circ k)(O)=t(k(O))=t(O)$. Similarly, $(t'\circ k')(O)=t'(O)$.

Thus $t(O)=t'(O)$. So the two translations $t$ and $t'$ do the same thing to a certain point $O$, and therefore they are the same.  Then from $t\circ k=t'\circ k'$ we conclude that $k=k'$.

Comment: Thanks! Will $\phi$ be the same as $t$ here since they both do the same thing; take the origin to $A$?

Comment: @Lays: I think you are confused: $t$ is a translation while $\phi$ can be any isometry; they are usually _not the same_. (Only in the rare case that $k$ happens to be the identity would they be the same.) Both taking the origin to the same image is only one thing; being the same requires taking _every_ point to the same image.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yup, I was. I just reread it again and I see now that we had to invoke both $\phi$ and $t$ into the proof, where they both are different. Thank you both!